# input string not in correct format...when converting a string to datetime...error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a parameter to a sql select query.

for some reason, no matter what i try, i keep getting the same error:
input string not in the corect format

and the suggestion:
when converting a string to datetime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the datetime object.

i'm stumped as to what to do. here's the code.

sql query:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE SearchAllPlayers
(
@personName,
@personPay,
@IDs
)

SELECT DISTINCT
                         person.personID, sports.sportsID, person.personName, person.personPay, sports.sport,

FROM            sports INNER JOIN
                person INNER JOIN
                personSport ON personSport.personID = person.personID
                       INNER JOIN
                personSport ON personSport.sportID = sports.sportsID

WHERE        (person.personName LIKE '%' + @personName + '%')
              AND
             (person.personPay >= @personPay OR 0 = @personPay)
              AND
             (person.regDate >= { fn CURDATE() }
              AND
             (sports.sportID IN
                    (SELECT   ID FROM dbo.fnSplitter(@IDs) AS fnSplitter_1) OR @IDs = 0)
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchGrid();
}

protected void searchGrid()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connSTR);
    com = new SqlCommand();
    conn.Open();

    com.Connection = conn;

    com.CommandText = "SearchAllPlayers";
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    string StringWithDelimiter = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < DropDownCheckBoxes1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DropDownCheckBoxes1.Items[i].Selected)
            StringWithDelimiter += DropDownCheckBoxes1.Items[i].Value + ";";
    }

    com.Parameters.Add("@personName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = personName.Text;

    //next line is where I am having problems
    com.Parameters.Add("@personPay", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = ??????
    com.Parameters.Add("@IDs", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StringWithDelimiter;

 so far i've tried the following combinations, all to know avail.


com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = playerPayTextBox.Text;
```

this doesn't seem to work, i get the following error:
"Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal."

so then i tried this:

```
com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = playerPayTextBox.tostring();
```

i get the same error:
"Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal."

which makes sense, so then i tried:

```
com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = decimal.parse(playerPayTextBox.tostring());
```

error: "Input string was not in a correct format." - then the datetime thing...

```
com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = decimal.parse(playerPayTextBox.text);
```

error: "Input string was not in a correct format." - then the datetime thing...

```
com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = convert.todecimal(playerPayTextBox.text);
```

error: "Input string was not in a correct format." - then the datetime thing...

```
com.parameters.add("@playerPay", sqldbtype.decimal).value = convert.todecimal(playerPayTextBox.text);
```

error: "Input string was not in a correct format." - then the datetime thing...

not sure what to do

Comment: What's the input string in question?

Comment: It's obviously that the playerPayTextBox.Text doesn't represent a decimal number. You should check for what values that textbox should accept.

Comment: have you tried debugging what is the value of playerPayTextBox.Text?

Comment: i should have mentioned that i'm a beginner at all of this. i've been following tutorials, so very unsure why i'm having this problem.

Comment: @king king: how do i check what values the textbox accepts? so far in my queries, i've been most concerned with a checkboxlist and whether the split function works or not. so i've left the textbox empty.

Comment: @user2369145 Do you have your textbox input by user or it displays text from some source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your input string is using decimal point symbol for your current culture!. If your input string does not match these rules, `decimal.Parse` throws the Input string was not in a correct format exception

If you for instance use the invariant culture:

```
decimal.Parse("17.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The dot will be the accepted decimal point.

You can read more about it over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There they also mention that the `decimal.TryParse` method is better suited for invariant culture parsing

Also (obviously), make sure your input string is not null, empty, or containing any non-numerical characters (except for the one, optional, dot or comma, depending on your culture)

Comment: really? I don't think so. 13.37 is exactly an example of a decimal number which is written in many English speaking countries.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! decimal.Parse is culture-specific! If I for instance do `decimal.Parse("17.5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat)`, it will parse correctly.

Comment: I think the default culture is "en-US", at least that's what in my projects I've done. Isn't that the default in your environment?

Comment: I'm from Sweden, so I have "sv-SE". And we do apparently use a comma. I have however updated the answer with some relevant information!

Comment: the problem seems to be the empty textboxes. now i have 2 questions... the first being, how do i allow for empty textboxes inthe queries? the second is...the splitfunction doesn't seem to work. i checked a couple of the textboxes and now i get this error at the "sqlDA.Fill(dS)" line... "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1;5;' to data type int."

Comment: If your text is empty, you could just check for it, and only add the parameter if it has a value. You could also use the [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) method